# working copy is on master branch, how to update from remote server?

Tags: git

My working copy is on master branch, how to update from remote server?

Say I working locally on my own custom branch, but I want to update the master with the remote branch, how would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git pull origin master
```

Or if instead of pulling into your local branch, you just wanted to update the branches you have locally that track `origin`:

```
git fetch
```

or

```
git remote update
```

if you're tracking multiple remote servers and want to update them all at once.

Comment: Do not use `git pull <remote> <remote-branch>:<local-branch>` syntax, unless you *really, really, really* know what it would do.  Just... don't.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your description that you understand the difference between "master" (a local branch) and "origin/master" (the master of the origin remote).  It's also not clear which you want to update.  A simple "git fetch origin" will update "origin/master" to reflect the upstream, but you can't change the local "master" until you check it out.

Comment: what do you know about GIT anyhow? :)

Comment: If you have local "master" branch checked out, then "git pull origin master" (or even simply "git pull origin", or perhaps even "git pull") would update this branch.